# flutter firebase data fetch

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

W/DynamiteModule(17985): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(17985): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(17985): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/nativeloader(17985): Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(17985): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libapuwareapusys.mtk.so:libapuwareapusys_v2.mtk.so:libapuwarexrp.mtk.so:libapuwarexrp_v2.mtk.so:libapuwareutils.mtk.so:libapuwareutils_v2.mtk.so:libapuwarehmp.mtk.so:libmcv_runtime_usdk.mtk.so:libneuron_graph_delegate.mtk.so:libneuronusdk_adapter.mtk.so:libtflite_mtk.mtk.so:libarmnn_ndk.mtk.so:libcmdl_ndk.mtk.so:libnir_neon_driver_ndk.mtk.so:libmvpu_runtime.mtk.so:libmvpu_runtime_pub.mtk.so:libmvpu_engine_pub.mtk.so:libmvpu_pattern_pub.mtk.so:libmvpuop_mtk_cv.mtk.so:libmvpuop_mtk_nn.mtk.so:libteeservice_client.trustonic.so:libSloganJni.oplus.so:libsuperNight.oplus.so
D/nativeloader(17985): Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(17985): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libapuwareapusys.mtk.so:libapuwareapusys_v2.mtk.so:libapuwarexrp.mtk.so:libapuwarexrp_v2.mtk.so:libapuwareutils.mtk.so:libapuwareutils_v2.mtk.so:libapuwarehmp.mtk.so:libmcv_runtime_usdk.mtk.so:libneuron_graph_delegate.mtk.so:libneuronusdk_adapter.mtk.so:libtflite_mtk.mtk.so:libarmnn_ndk.mtk.so:libcmdl_ndk.mtk.so:libnir_neon_driver_ndk.mtk.so:libmvpu_runtime.mtk.so:libmvpu_runtime_pub.mtk.so:libmvpu_engine_pub.mtk.so:libmvpu_pattern_pub.mtk.so:libmvpuop_mtk_cv.mtk.so:libmvpuop_mtk_nn.mtk.so:libteeservice_client.trustonic.so:libSloganJni.oplus.so:libsuperNight.oplus.so
W/ple.ambikabind(17985): Loading /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@com.android.location.provider.jar@classes.odex non-executable as it requires an image which we failed to load
D/nativeloader(17985): Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader(17985): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libapuwareapusys.mtk.so:libapuwareapusys_v2.mtk.so:libapuwarexrp.mtk.so:libapuwarexrp_v2.mtk.so:libapuwareutils.mtk.so:libapuwareutils_v2.mtk.so:libapuwarehmp.mtk.so:libmcv_runtime_usdk.mtk.so:libneuron_graph_delegate.mtk.so:libneuronusdk_adapter.mtk.so:libtflite_mtk.mtk.so:libarmnn_ndk.mtk.so:libcmdl_ndk.mtk.so:libnir_neon_driver_ndk.mtk.so:libmvpu_runtime.mtk.so:libmvpu_runtime_pub.mtk.so:libmvpu_engine_pub.mtk.so:libmvpu_pattern_pub.mtk.so:libmvpuop_mtk_cv.mtk.so:libmvpuop_mtk_nn.mtk.so:libteeservice_client.trustonic.so:libSloganJni.oplus.so:libsuperNight.oplus.so
D/nativeloader(17985): Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=libOpenCL.so, library_path=/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~L_db_OhwyVl7woXd8w9duA==/com.google.android.gms-zQmM21sBq1qBqq4jPvxekw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
V/NativeCrypto(17985): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 295 native methods...
W/ple.ambikabind(17985): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(17985): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/ple.ambikabind(17985): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/ple.ambikabind(17985): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/flutter (17985): Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'

"==============      source code      ======================"

```
final firebaseInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Future<void> getData() async {
      //use a Async-await function to get the data
      var response = await firebaseInstance
          .collection("user")
          .doc('995')
          .get(); //get the data

      print(response);
    }

getData();
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the late answer and my English.

Try adding to GooglePlayServices.Base and GooglePlayServices.Basement libraries.

I do not work with Flutter, but if someone has the same problems in Xamarin, I hope it will come in handy:

I faced the same problem using Xamarin.Firabase.Analytics 121.2.0.1
I don’t know what exactly influenced the correction, but after adding Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, everything worked.
To add libraries, migrate to AndroidX.
If some library cannot be added, watch dependent libraries and add gradually.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is asking. I hope you are confident your post answers it. Otherwise, answer well-asked questions.

Comment: I think the question is where did the above error come from.  answer: most likely in the absence of dependencies...